# Noise music player font problem

Tags: release-loki, music, fonts

I'm running Loki with latest upgrades prior to Feb 25 2017. Some songs' names written in Cyrillic appear screwed. Interestingly, it doesn't apply to all Cyrillic names:

[image]

Now these files with cryptic names in the Files app. Looks very normal:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HOW I SOLVED IT:**

This [tutorial](http://ask.xmodulo.com/convert-mp3-id3-tag-encodings-linux.html) helped me. Basically, I did this:

```
sudo apt install python-mutagen

find . -name "*mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 mid3iconv -e WINDOWS-1251 -d
```

Be careful, this command directly edits the files, so before doing it, you have to be sure that it's the right encoding. Or just make a backup. Also you have to re-import that song to see the changes or play it from another directory.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mp3 tag coding issue in some files, you should ensure that all your mp3 tags are in utf-8.

Comment: I don't have this problem on Windows. Maybe it's not utf-8 but going through all of them and changing the tags kinda sucks. However, maybe it's possible to write a script for this, but I need to think about it.

Comment: Glad that it helped: you should answer your question not edit your question with the answer.